# Unexpected "Expected Identifier" error

Tags: objective-c, ios

The following two methods are in one of my controllers.  the buttonPressed method is connected to a button and works properly.
However, I get an error when I add the call to workWithAString.  Wondering what I'm missing here and would appreciate your advice.

```
-(NSString *) workWithAString: (NSString *) string1
{

NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string1];

// Here I will do some other things with string2

return string2;

}


-(IBAction)button1Pressed
{
NSString *modifiedString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:InputValue.text];
modifiedString1 = [[self workWithAString: modifiedString1 ];  // Expected identifier error here


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two brackets for some reason ...

```
[self workWithAString:modifiedString1];
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.  Thanks very much.